# How to Click a ImageButton using Robotium

Tags: robotium

please refer the image.

In the image (which is blue color is selected one). I want to click on the imageView.
I am not sure how to select a imageView, when multiple linear layout is there.

```
-Relative Layout:
     -(0)Linear Layout
       -(0)TabWidget
          -(0) LinearLayout
                (0)imageView
          -(1) LinearLayout
                (0)imageView
          -(2) LinearLayout
                (0)imageView (I want Click this image View).
```

Comment: Do you have any Ids at all? even on the relative layout?

Comment: No, There are no Idsfor relative layouts,only the TabWidget has  Id as "tabs".

Answer (score 1):

If there are no ids and the Relative Layout is root layout, you can click on image view with index 2.

```
solo.clickOnImage(2);
```

Comment: I want to Click on the Actionbar  search button.itried in bellow way but it din't work for me.  solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.drawable.ic_menu_search); please help me on this, advance thanks.